# How to setup Advanced Content Filter to not remove drupal-entity tags?

Tags: entities, wysiwyg

I use CKEditor to create content. And Media Plugin to upload and manage images.

Now I have a problem that as soon as I activate `Advanced Content Filter` in CKEditor settings, my images are removed. I think problem is, that they are implemented like this:

```
    <drupal-entity class="media-element" data-entity-embed-display="image:image" 
        data-entity-id="2589" data-entity-type="file" data-fid="2589" 
        data-media-element="1"></drupal-entity>
```

I tried to insert `drupal-entity` in `extra allowed content`, but it doesn't change anything.

As long as I do not save this node with activated ACF the images are shown on my website. This is because first I created nodes with deactivated ACF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

- admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full->
- Advanced Options ->
- Custom JavaScript configuration ->
- Paste in:  **config.allowedContent = true;**
- Save

Comment: At the end I edited the config.js and set `allowed_content` to t.